# Inserted record not showing up

Tags: mysql

I have a web based inventory database setup so that when a user adds a new purchase order(PO) it is automatically inserted into the stocks table. Now, when I go to the grid view of my stocks table the inserted record shows up, but when I go check it out on the database it is not there, what seems to be the problem?

This is the link to my code: http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=BiYmDQt1

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution to my problem, looks like mysql workbench just shows the first 1000 records in a table so all I have to do is toggle row limitations for all records to show up.

Answer (score 1):

What is between your page and the database, do you add everything to an array or an xml file or something before writing it to the database, that your grid view reads from? can we see some code? :)

maybe the issue is related to this part being commented, out, or maybe its so late I am delirious

```
         /* DbParameter parStockOut = dbStockInsert.CreateParameter();
            parStockOut.ParameterName = "@Stock_Out";
            parStockOut.Value = "";
            dbStockInsert.Parameters.Add(parStockOut);*/
```

Comment: My grid view of the stocks is connected to a mysql datasource. I can view POs that are newly inserted in the mysql database but not the stocks.

Comment: and when you say you are checking the database you mean through like the command prompt or some other SQL tool like phpmyadmin? 

does the datasource need to be commited to the database after its updated? what language are you using php, java? does a try catch throw an error that might help?

Comment: I'm checking them using mysql workbench. There are no errors when I insert POs. I'm using C#

Comment: so they insert the PO and it shows in the grid view, but if you restart your application (like the server and everything) do these records still show up? or are they lost? I am still thinking that maybe the data source is just in memory and needs to be commited to the database??

Comment: I'll try what you said tomorrow as I'm getting sleepy. I'll post as soon as I can. Thanks.

Comment: Its late and I hate looking at code when its late but could the problem be that this part is commented out, see my original answer

Comment: That part that is commented out is for the insertion of data into the stock out field of the stock table, so I don't think thats the problem, though I'm not to sure.